# pandas map list values to corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a table (df) which has an "actions" column that holds a list which contains 2 values out of 4 options:
**do1,do2,do3,do4**

```
print(df['actions'])

0    [do1, do4]
1    [do2, do1]
2    [do2, do3]
3    [do2, do1]
4    [do4, do2]
```

I'm looking for the right map function in order to add 4 columns to the table, and populate each column with the corresponding values from the 'actions' column. for example:

```
print(df)
do1, do2, do3, do4
1    0     0    1
1    1     0    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'action': {'0': ['do1', 'do4'],
                              '1': ['do2', 'do1'],
                              '2': ['do2', 'do3'],
                              '3': ['do2', 'do1'],
                              '4': ['do4', 'do2']}})

df = pd.get_dummies(df.action.explode()).groupby(level=0).agg(sum)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   do1  do2  do3  do4
0    1    0    0    1
1    1    1    0    0
2    0    1    1    0
3    1    1    0    0
4    0    1    0    1
```